# extracting column headers

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data frame (data) from which I will like to extract and print column headers where ever there is a non-zero element:

```
  M1 M2 M3 M4
2  0  1  0 1
5  1 -1  0 0
7  0  1  1 0
```

Required output:

```
2: M2 M4
5: M1 M2
7: M2 M3
```

So far my R code is not working:

```
colnames(data)[which(data[2] !=0),]
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Since you are not guaranteed that all rows will have the same number of column names you should be prepared to get a list as output.

Comment: `colnames(data)` is a vector, so you shouldn't have a comma inside [], I guess. Use `colnames(data)[which(data[2,]!=0)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the more general case of irregular results:

```
dat <- structure(list(M1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), M2 = c(1L, -1L, 1L), M3 = -1:1, 
M4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "5", "7"))

> dat
  M1 M2 M3 M4
2  0  1 -1  1
5  1 -1  0  0
7  0  1  1  0
```

The inner apply "loop" constructs a logical set of vectors. Because R is column oriented the second level of processing is done on columns. The outer apply "loop" extracts the appropriate items from colnames:

```
 apply( apply(dat,1, as.logical) , 2, function(ll) colnames(dat)[ll] ) 
$`2`
[1] "M2" "M3" "M4"

$`5`
[1] "M1" "M2"

$`7`
[1] "M2" "M3"
```

You could also have extracted the array indicator version of which() and then process the results:

```
 > which(dat != 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
  row col
5   2   1
2   1   2
5   2   2
7   3   2
2   1   3
7   3   3
2   1   4
```

Comment: Thanks DWin. The code (apply( apply(dat,1, as.logical) , 2, function(ll) colnames(dat)[ll] ) ) worked brilliantly! Kindly explain the code a bit.

Comment: When you look at R code, try to find the innermost expression and then "think outward" from there. The inner function returns a logical result on the basis of row values and that is then used as a logical vector to choose from column names of the dataframe. Since it got returned as a set of logical columns, the margin needed to be "2" instead of what you might have expected.

Answer (score 5):

This will always return a list:

```
Map(`[`, list(names(df)), split(col(df)[df != 0],
                                row(df)[df != 0]))

# [[1]]
# [1] "M2" "M4"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "M1" "M2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "M2" "M3"
```

(And you can wrap in inside `setNames(..., rownames(df))` if you want the list to share `df`'s row names.)

Comment: I appreciate your help flodel. Please explain how map() is used in this context. Thanks

Comment: `Map` is like `mapply` if you are familiar with the function, except it always returns a list. The syntax here is `Map(f, a, b)` where `a` and `b` are lists (you can think of them as vectors). `Map` will loop through these two lists and run `f(a[[i]], b[[i]])`. Note that `a` has length 1 so it will be recycled, so it is in fact running `f(a[[1]], b[[i]])` for all `i`. Now if you replace `f`, `a`, `b` by what they are here above, it should make some sense.

Answer (score 2):

I add 1 in the first row to treat the irregular case

```
mm <- read.table(text='M1 M2 M3 M4
2  0  1  1 1
5  1 -1  0 0
7  0  1  1 0',header=TRUE)


res <- apply(mm != 0,1,function(x)colnames(mm)[x])

$`2`
[1] "M2" "M3" "M4"

$`5`
[1] "M1" "M2"

$`7`
[1] "M2" "M3"
```

**EDIT** to be consistent and return a list :

```
res <- apply(mm != 0,1,function(x)colnames(mm)[x])     
if (!is.null(dim(res)) split(res,seq_along(res[,1]))
```

Comment: I think both yours and DWin's answer have that problem that they will return a list or a matrix depending on the input. To be consistent it should always return a list.

Comment: Thanks agstudy.  Is the update to be run after the previous line? I ran it and I got: "Error: unexpected symbol in "if (!is.null(dim(res)) split""